# How do I to lose the results of running python in the form of an array (ex: array ([1, 2, ..., 6, 7, 8])

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, arraylist

example array : 
[array([0.84312789, 0.75129959, 0.88778234, ..., 0.96588262, 0.98853215,
       0.52034823])]

How do I know the value of (...) in the array list ?
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a list with an array in it, so your array is accessible with `[0]`.

You can access elements in an array the same way you access list elements. You also have to supply a character code to the `array` module which describes the type of elements in the array.

example

```
from array import array
# 'd' describes double
x = array('d', [0.84312789, 0.75129959, 0.88778234, 0.96588262, 0.98853215, 0.52034823])
print(x[0][0])
```

prints
`0.84312789`

Comment: Thank you, but if i use (i will explain what i mean)
example :

b = [array([0.84312789, 0.75129959, 0.88778234, ..., 0.96588262, 0.98853215, 0.52034823])]
a = array ('d' , [b])
print (a) or print (a [0] [0])

result is error -> TypeError: must be real number, not list

the point I would like to know the value of the result array (. ..) ? how could i change the list become a real number ? thank you